# android-kotlin JsonObject JsonArray send request data via POST

Tags: android, json, kotlin, post, retrofit2

I want to send data request via post to server I want to know How can I add data in array

```
data class City(
   @SerializedName("cityId")
   val cityId: Int?,
   @SerializedName("detail")
   val detail: List<String?>
)
```

Request

```
data class CityRequest(
   @SerializedName("listCity")
   val listCity: List<City?>
)
```

Response

```
data class CityResponse(
   @SerializedName("code")
   val code: String?,
   @SerializedName("status")
   val status: Boolean?,
   @SerializedName("message")
   val message: String?
)
```

API Server

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("city")
suspend fun sendCityContent(@Body listCity: CityRequest?): 
Call<CityResponse?>
```

Connect Service
I don't know how I can add information to this section in question.

```
private suspend fun sendDataCity(city: List<city?>) {
    val retrofit = clientCity
    val sendDataToServer = retrofit?.create(CityService::class.java)
    val call = sendDataToServer?.sendCityContent(CityRequest(city))
    call?.enqueue(object : Callback<CityResponse?> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<CityResponse?>, response: Response<CityResponse?>) {
            val getResponse = response.body()
            Timber.tag("SALE_CITY: ").d("code: %s", getResponse?.code)
            Timber.tag("SALE_CITY: ").d("status: %s", getResponse?.status)
            Timber.tag("SALE_CITY: ").d("message: %s", getResponse?.message)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<CityResponse?>, t: Throwable?) {
            t?.printStackTrace()
        }

    })
}
```

JSON Simple

```
{
"city": [
    {
        "cityId": 1,
        "answer": [
            "1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "questionId": 2,
        "answer": [
            "2.1",
            "2.2"
        ]
    }
]}
```

What do I have to do next?
Can you have a sample add data in array for me?
Things I want

```
cityId = 1
detail = "1.1", "1.2"

cityId = 2 
detail = "2.1", "2.2"
```

thank you

Comment: what kind of error you are getting can you post error here ?

Comment: I don't know how I can add data. Because it's a two-layer array

Comment: you must be getting some error or something after executing the above code, post that or clearly mention what format your server accepts and what kind of format you have

Answer (score 0):

One issue i can see with your request is the key is different from what you are sending might be different check that. it should be `city`  not `listCity` as given.

```
data class CityRequest(
   @SerializedName("city")
   val city: List<City?>
)
```

and your city class should have these keys `answer` which you have mentioned as `details`

```
data class City(
   @SerializedName("cityId")
   val cityId: Int?,
   @SerializedName("answer")
   val answer: List<String?>
)
```

I guess you are just sending with wrong keys that might be the reason the server is not accepting the request. make the above change it should work post if you get error.

Comment: I need an example of adding data 
cityId = 1
detail = "1.1", "1.2"
cityId = 1
detail = "1.1", "1.2"